# Degree completed 2 years back but have PM experience for more than 5 years

Tags: pmp, education

I have been performing Project Management for more than 5 years now. I have completed my Degree in Distance Education program. Can I use this degree to qualify for 4500 hour in last 36 months? I am asking this because my degree is completed only 2 years or 24 months back.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only PMI can answer these questions. PMI does not consult PM:SE when making these determinations.  Any answer is merely an opinion without authority; PM:SE has no greater influence over PMI than a random person selected from the phone book.

Comment: I disagree. The criteria are published. There is nothing hidden. No opinion is being made about his specific education or application, only interpretation against published criteria.

Comment: Concur with David. Pretty much everything here is some kind of opinion. That being said, people who have PMPs are typically very familiar with the process and requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The education criterion is a yes or no test. There is no language that specifies when a candidate earned the degree.

Avoid reading more into the criteria than what is there. Same advice applies for the test.